# Google OAuth 2.0 Client-Token used on Server

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

I plan on accessing the Google Calendar via a Server application and using an authorization token received from the Android client device via AccountManager (full code in this blog post: [Link](http://blog.tomtasche.at/2013/05/google-oauth-on-android-using.html)).

Now does anyone know whether or not any problems could arise here? (e.g. Token not refreshable by the server, or token only valid when used by an Android device)

Also, I did request such a token on my phone and also got one (can see it in the debugger, so it was issued by Google), but it doesn't show in my authorized applications neither [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1) nor [here](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en).
Is it possible that the token only gets listed after it has been used at least once? (If so, that would be strange imo, since it could be used anytime?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow

Comment: Additionally to your answer which is very much related to Google+, we found this document https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth which exactly explains how to obtain an offline token for a web server application by means of a client application with any scope.

Answer (score 0):

**"Now does anyone know whether or not any problems could arise here? "**

I've done the opposite (server token on a client) without any problem. Once you have an access token token, you're good to go from anywhere. This is why they expire so quickly.

.

**"Is it possible that the token only gets listed after it has been used at least once?"**

The Account Permissions page is listing Projects that your user has authorized. So projects appear on that list the moment the user grants access, regardless of whether any tokens have been issued or used.

Comment: That is strange, I successfully got a token but my Project is not listed. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: My only suggestions are #1 you're looking at different users, #2 a google bug. #1 is the most likely :-(